# sphinx-4 NullPointerException at startRecognition

Tags: cmusphinx, sphinx4

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4), and it crashes upon startup after having lots of problems with the dictionary and models, such as.

`The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'humphrey'`

and

`Dec 18, 2014 1:14:50 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.HMMTree addPronunciation
SEVERE: Missing HMM for unit T with lc=N rc=EH1
13:14:50.601 SEVERE lexTreeLinguist    Bad HMM Unit: EH1`

I loaded [this dictionary](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/cmusphinx/code/trunk/cmudict/cmudict.0.6d)  and got the language and acoustic models from [their SourceForge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/)

It then crashes with this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.HMMNode.getBaseUnit(HMMTree.java:506)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.HMMNode.<init>(HMMTree.java:484)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.Node.addSuccessor(HMMTree.java:165)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.HMMTree$EntryPoint.createEntryPointMap(HMMTree.java:1163)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.HMMTree$EntryPointTable.createEntryPointMaps(HMMTree.java:1021)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.HMMTree.compile(HMMTree.java:795)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.HMMTree.<init>(HMMTree.java:716)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.LexTreeLinguist.generateHmmTree(LexTreeLinguist.java:433)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.LexTreeLinguist.compileGrammar(LexTreeLinguist.java:420)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.LexTreeLinguist.allocate(LexTreeLinguist.java:337)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.WordPruningBreadthFirstSearchManager.allocate(WordPruningBreadthFirstSearchManager.java:232)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.AbstractDecoder.allocate(AbstractDecoder.java:92)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.allocate(Recognizer.java:167)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveSpeechRecognizer.startRecognition(LiveSpeechRecognizer.java:46)
    at com.test.sphinxtest.App.main(App.java:25)
```

Here's my code.

```
package com.test.sphinxtest;

import java.io.IOException;

import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Configuration;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveSpeechRecognizer;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        configuration.setAcousticModelPath("models/acousticmodel/en-us");
        configuration.setDictionaryPath("dictionary/cmudict-0.6d");
        configuration.setLanguageModelPath("models/languagemodel/en-us.lm");

        try {
            LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
            recognizer.startRecognition(true);
            SpeechResult result = recognizer.getResult();
            recognizer.stopRecognition();
            while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null) {
                System.out.println(result.getHypothesis());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct dictionary should not have stress marks, you can download it from here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/master/model/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict

Comment: What does it mean for a dictionary to be "correct"? How do I know which ones are "correct" and which ones are "incorrect"?

Comment: Dictionary phoneset must match the phoneset of the acoustic model. If it matches the dictionary is correct otherwise incorrect and you get errors like above. This issue is covered in tutorial.

Comment: Where is this issue covered in the tutorial? Maybe I'm looking at the wrong tutorial, or following it out of order or something.

Comment: Oh, I found it here http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam  This is under the "Advanced user documentation". I'm not an advanced user yet. I'm up in the "Getting started" section :)