# Sphinx4 figuring out correct models

Tags: cmusphinx, sphinx4

I am trying to use the Sphinx4 library for speech recognition, but I cannot seem to figure out the correct combination of acoustic model-dictionary-language model. I have tried out various combinations and I get a different error every time.

I am trying to follow the tutorial on http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4. I do not have a config.xml as I would if I was using ConfigurationManager instead of Configuration, because there is no perceivable way of passing the location of the config file to the Configuration itself (ConfigMgr takes it as an argument to the constructor); and that might be my problem right there. I just do not know how to point to one, and since the tutorial says "It is possible to configure low-level components of the application through XML file although you should do that ONLY IF you understand what is going on.", I assume having a config.xml file is not compulsory.

Combining the latest dictionary (7b - obtained from Sourceforge) with the latest acoustic model (cmusphinx-en-us-5.2.tar.gz - from SF again) and the language model (cmusphinx-5.0-en-us.lm.gz - from SF again) results in `NullPointerException` in `startRecognition`. The issue is similar to the problem here: [sphinx-4 NullPointerException at startRecognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555090/sphinx-4-nullpointerexception-at-startrecognition), but the link given in the answer no longer works. I obtained 0.7a from SF (since that is the dict the link seems to point at), but I am getting even earlier in the execution `Error loading word: ;;;` when I use that one. I tried downloading latest models and dict from the Github repo, that results in `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 16128, Size: 16128`.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use latest code from github

http://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4

as described by tutorial

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4

Correct models (en-us) are already included, you should not replace anything. You should not configure any XML files, use samples as provided in the sources.

Comment: Only after I cloned the github repository was I able to see that it was the Context class that used the config.xml file, apparently that was my problem, as I suspected. Only using a main class where I set the Configuration object's acoustic, dict and language model path is not enough; the path to the config.xml is set with a ConfigMgr inside the Context class. Thanks for the help.